# How to pass proxy password to the app from WiFi settings

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I read proxy details entered by user on WiFo settings of iPad device in code.

I got everything except ProxyPassword.

Comment: It seems to be a security feature. I would not trust a device able to disclose my password at any random application...

Comment: In the comments under an answer, the OP gives a lot of code. I therefore think this question is missing a [mcve], and it can be closed.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get the proxy password as an application.  This is protected data and you will have to prompt your user separately if you want the password. Often the proxy password is also something like the user's Active Directory password, so it would be a huge security issue if you were able to do this.

Comment: Thanks a Lot Michael :-
I am using below Code 
        NSDictionary *proxySettings = NSMakeCollectable([(NSDictionary *)CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings() autorelease]);
        NSArray *proxies = NSMakeCollectable([(NSArray *)CFNetworkCopyProxiesForURL((CFURLRef)[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://e-planner.com.au"], (CFDictionaryRef)proxySettings) autorelease]);
        NSDictionary *settings = [proxies objectAtIndex:0];
[settings objectForKey:(NSString *)kCFProxyHostNameKey]
[[settings objectForKey:(NSString *)kCFProxyPortNumberKey]
[settings objectForKey:(NSString *)kCFProxyUsernameKey]

Comment: [settings objectForKey:(NSString *)kCFProxyPasswordKey] is giving blank value

Comment: The keys for username and password are optional and will only be present if the username or password could be extracted from the information passed in (i.e. either the URL itself or the proxy dictionary supplied).  These APIs do not consult any external credential stores (such as the Keychain) where the proxy password is traditionally stored.

Comment: Hi Michael,

What does it means : * (i.e. either the URL itself or the proxy dictionary supplied)*

Comment: The keys for username and password are optional and will only be present if the username or password could be extracted from the information passed in (i.e. either the URL itself or the proxy dictionary supplied). These APIs do not consult any external credential stores (such as the Keychain) where the proxy password is traditionally stored. *Didnt get what does it mean*

Comment: Basically, you won't get values for those fields unless the user sets up the proxy in a way that would allow the username and password to be retrieved easily.  So instead of entering the proxy as `http://web-proxy.example.com:8080`. and using the username and password fields (which would be secure), the user would need to have put the proxy in as `http://username:password@web-proxy.example.com:8080/`. Unfortunately, no one does that because it exposes your password.  This is also why Apple won't allow you yo query the system settings for a password the user hasn't willfully exposed.